# Copying Excel Formula and controlling relative reference

Tags: excel, copying

In Excel I want to copy a formula down and control the relative cell reference.

For example

In A1 if the formula was =B1 and I copied the A1 formula down to A3 the formula in A3 would be =B3.  Is there a way of copying the formula in A1 to A3 and have it equal B2?

Answer (score 1):

That's the default copying behaviour in Excel. Did you try it? In fact, if you want to disable it, you have to write $ in front of the fixed row and/or column denominator, so for example $E$1 would be fixed when copied (useful for things that remain constant).

Edit: I think I can imagine what happens: You probably tried to copy the cell *contents* from the formula editor field. Copy the *cell* instead, so just mark the cell in the grid by highlighting it, copy it, highlight your target and paste.

Edit2: And please note that you can just drag the little square at the edge of a highlighted cell to apply that cell's formula to an entire area, using the same relative referencing as with copying.

Comment: I never knew that! I've been just fixing the formula's for every row.

Comment: See also my edit just now, I think that will help you when doing simple things like getting sums for multiple columns in one row.